# How to check if column name exists when using Spring jdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, jdbctemplate

I am using jdbcTemplate to write data to my Oracle DB. I would like to reuse my code for the same table but in two different enviroments and the difference between these two enviroments is only one column missing. So before writing the data I need to check if the column is there or not to use the correct sql query, other I will get an exception. So I would like to have something like:

```
if(column3IsMissing){
    String sql = String.format("insert into %s %s", MYTABLE,
                "(column1, column2) values (?, ?)");
}else{
    String sql = String.format("insert into %s %s", MYTABLE,
                "(column1, column2, column3) values (?, ?, ?)");

}
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, data, types);
```

Can anyone give me hint how should I implement the column3IsMissing check here? Thank you very much in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Oracle offer three different views to get table columns information: ALL_TAB_COLUMNS, USER_TAB_COLUMNS and DBA_TAB_COLUMNS.

You can run query like below with JDBC, to confirm if column exists before running your insert query.

```
select column_name from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'MYTABLE';
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get check the columns size. put all your column into array and check if 
columnSize = 2.

`String[] columnList = {column1,column2,column3);`

`if(columnList.size()==2){
    String sql = String.format("insert into %s %s", MYTABLE,
                "(column1, column2) values (?, ?)");`
`}else{
    String sql = String.format("insert into %s %s", MYTABLE,
                "(column1, column2, column3) values (?, ?, ?)");`

`}
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, data, types);`